# Angular datepicker directive with function binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am beginner with angular.
Please help me fix [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/dhWg3K2txGeRrz8LKpfW?p=preview)

I am trying to use only one call back for onSelect callback of jquery UI datepicker widget which is in my controller instead of repeating the callback function in each directive (yes I do have multiple directives for sake of experiment).

But I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'onSelect' in 19/10/2016

Here is my code

> HTML

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
        <input type="text" my-datepicker ng-model="date" date="date" on-select="onSelect()"/>
        <input type="button" ng-click="submitDate()" value="Submit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

> JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.date = "frommyController";
    $scope.submitDate = function(){
        console.log($scope.date);
    };
    $scope.onSelect = function(value, picker){
        scope.date = value;
        scope.$parent.$digest();
    }
}]);
app.directive('myDatepicker', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            date: "=",
            onSubmit: "&onSelect"
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelController){
            scope.date = "fromdirevtive";
            element.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: scope.onSubmit
            });
        }
    }
})
```

can someone help me understanding what wrong am I doing here?

Comment: don't fotgot to appricate my work.

Comment: @chiragpatel thanks for your help chirag. I understood that since this callback is supposed to be called from outer environment and not by angular. This is not achievable.

Answer (score 1):

I have a created a new plunkr using your plunkr. Refer this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cvCmY4LugjtR0xNJChYx?p=preview) for solution.

Issues found with your plunkr:

1. The method signature was incorrect in index.html.
2. The way on invoking a callback with & binding in angular directive.

I have just corrected the above issues. Also instead of using the link function I have used a controller for the directive since it gives me more control in terms of interaction with the directive.

The correct way of invoking a callback in angular directive is by passing   an object as the argument. The keys of the object should be the parameters of the callback function. Refer line number 27 of app.js

> Code - app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.date = "frommyController";
    $scope.submitDate = function() {
      console.log($scope.date);
    };
    $scope.onSelect = function(value, picker) {
      console.log(value);
      console.log(picker);
      $scope.date = value;
      $scope.$parent.$digest();

    }
  }
]);
app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      date: "<",
      onSelect: "&"
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: "ngModel",
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      vm = this;
      vm.$scope = $scope;
      vm.onSelect = function(value, picker) {
        vm.$scope.onSelect({
          value: value,
          picker: picker
        })
      }

      $element.datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: vm.onSelect
      });

    }
  }
})


<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" my-datepicker ng-model="date" date="date" on-select="onSelect(value,picker)" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="submitDate()" value="Submit" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

**Option 1:**

Call your callback function in the directive like below:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.date = "frommyController";
    $scope.submitDate = function(){
        console.log($scope.date);
    };
    $scope.onSelect = function(value, picker){
      alert('');
        scope.date = value;
        scope.$parent.$digest();
    }
}]);
app.directive('myDatepicker', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            date: "=",
            onSubmit: "&onSelect"
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelController){
            scope.date = "fromdirevtive";
            element.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: function(){scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.onSubmit();
                }); }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

**Option 2:**

Use publisher/subscriber model to do some stuff in your parent controller..like below

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.date = "frommyController";
    $scope.submitDate = function(){
        console.log($scope.date);
    };

    $scope.$on('event',function()
    {
      alert('listener');
        scope.date = value;
        scope.$parent.$digest();
    });

}]);
app.directive('myDatepicker', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            date: "="
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelController){
            scope.date = "fromdirevtive";
            element.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: function(){scope.$apply(function() {
                  console.log(scope)
                    scope.$emit('event')
                });}
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below directory , instead of your directory:

```
app.directive('myDatepicker', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            date: "=",
            onSubmit: "&onSelect"
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelController){
            scope.date = "fromdirevtive";
            element.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect:function(date) {

                scope.$apply(function() {
                    modelController.$setViewValue(date); 
                }); 
            }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: thats what I want to avoid to create multiple callbacks in multiple directives.

Comment: @nikhilmehta , check updated answer , now this is  work for you. I also try this in your plunker and it is working , you can check replacing this code in your plunker

Comment: then there is no use of passing onSubmit to the directive scope

Comment: @nikhilmehta , if it is helpful to you then don't forgot to appreciate my work

Comment: you are right these are the ways through which I can achieve the thing. But I am learning angular and want to use only one callback for onSelect in multiple datepicker directives via reference.

Comment: @nikhilmehta , there is no solution for which you want , i also use same thing in my application multiple times

Comment: In that case can you please explain me the actual use of function binding please. I mean then may be I got the concept of function binding wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124977/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-nikhil-mehta).

Comment: @nikhilmehta , without function binding you can not get a selected date

Comment: thanks for your help chirag. I understood that since this callback is supposed to be called from outer environment and not by angular. This is not achievable.